# Where does SharePoint Webpart store a Nintex Form?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, nintex, reference

I am working with a SharePoint webpage which has a webpart. This webpart uses a Nintex Form. I wanted to change that Nintex form, so I created a new one and published it on https://mysite/NintexForms/Forms/AllItems.aspx

The problem is that the new one doesn't appear. 
I deleted all other Nintex Forms and realized that the webpart does use a Nintex Form but it isn't referenced to the link above. How can I find out which Nintex Form the webpart uses? I do have SharePoint designer so I can look up pretty much anything, but I can't find  the reference and where I have to upload my new Nintex Form.

Comment: that question is probably best asked on Nintex forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Nintex Form is at the List / Library Level.  To change the form in the webpart you have to go to the list / library that is being displayed in the webpart and update the form there.